# Using an array to set variable name

Tags: php

I'm trying to use some mysql data in creating part of a variable name to refer to another variable already declared elsewhere. Basically how can I get the $damage_name be part of the if statement boolean check?

```
$conditions = array(
        'bent_num' => 0,
        'spine_torn' => 0,
        'pages_torn' => 0,
        'water_damage' => 0,
        'pages_highlighted' => 0,
        'pages_noted' => 0,
        'taped' => 0,
        'stained' => 0,
        'mold' => 0,
        'scratched' => 0
        );
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
    {           
        $damage_name = $conditions[$row['type']]; 

        if (isset($conditions[$row['type']]) && $_SESSION[SELL_is_ . $damage_name . ];  == 'y')
        {
            $condition_score = $condition_score - $row['value'];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Broken syntax and concatenation. Try:

```
$_SESSION['SELL_is_' . $damage_name];
```

- SELL_is_ needs to be quoted.
- You had an extra concatenation operator after `$damage_name`
- An extra semicolon after the closing square bracket.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean:

```
$_SESSION[constant("SELL_is_" . $damage_name)]
```

I'm assuming SELL_is_ is a `define`d constant (because of the capitalization). To get the value of a define, either use the full name, or use `constant`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$_SESSION[SELL_is_ . $damage_name . ];
```

should be

```
$_SESSION["SELL_is_" . $damage_name];
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
if (isset($conditions[$row['type']]) && $_SESSION["SELL_is_$damage_name"]  == 'y')
```